# how to convert compressed rar or video file to binary code and store it in text file and reverse

Tags: c++

how to convert compressed rar or video file to binary code and store it in text file the restore the compressed file from the binary in the text file again
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("filename.ext");

Comment: You want to decompress RAR and video files?

Comment: It might help if you explained *why* you want to do this; there are various ways it can be done but it's hard to know which one is appropriate without knowing what the purpose is.

Comment: A rar or video file *is* a binary file already; there's no need to write it to a text file. You can use ReadAllBytes on it directly. Also, like @JeremyFriesner said, please explain your rationale . I think this might be a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: i want to make video file made of binary code of any file like matrix movie and iam c++ junior so i dont have enough experience